# List Database Entries According to Condition MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am developing an MVC 3 application in C# and I would like to know how to list database entries, based on a condition. In my case, I only want to display invoices that have the status "Paid" or "Partly Paid".

So this is where I list them:

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {

        var invoices = db.Invoice.Include(c => c.Client);
        return View(db.Invoice.ToList());
    }
```

How I would I add the condition into this code?

Thanks,
Amy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{

    var invoices = db.Invoice.Include(c => c.Client).Where(i => i.Status !="Confirmed";
    return View(invoices.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. That's not working yet - is there a way of saying Where not equal to "Confirmed" maybe?

Comment: @Amy: Updated the post to reflect the same. Pls chk

Comment: @Amy: Also notice that the View should return `invoices` not `db.Invoice`

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that invoices change. That works great, thank you :)